# How to find an ES6 import module without a relative path?

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

I have an ES6 import.

```
import MyAwesomeComponent from 'packageNameOnlyWithoutPath';
```

I want to inspect the file `packageNameOnlyWithoutPath`. But I can't find it. I looked in `node_modules` but I don't see it there. So it might be hiding out elsewhere in the app.

Is there a canonical way to find the path that leads to `packageNameOnlyWithoutPath`?

Comment: pretty sure anything without any path notation ("./") or "../" etc resolves to node_modules. But i would say just open the directory in windows and use the search to find it

Comment: @ShanonJackson: Yes. You are correct. Somehow I must have opened the wrong node_modules.

Comment: @ShanonJackson: Oops. This is still a valid question. I just found the resolve path and it was NOT in `node_modules`. (It was actually in my `src` directory.) I just got lucky this time. So if anyone can answer this I and others might benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to take a look at index.js file in the packageNameOnlyWithoutPath folder inside the node_modules. 
Else use text editors which supports goToDefinition plugin

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Check resolve aliases in Webpack (or similar bundler) config or `.babelrc`

There's two places you can check first.

1. If you are using a bundler like Webpack, resolve aliases can be declared in the Webpack config file (usually webpack.config.js).
2. But I have also recently started using pure babel and node. The reoslves can also be declared in the .babelrc file (cleaner approach IMHO).

You should find what you're looking for in one of the above.